# Extend private protocol in Objective-C or Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols, private

I have a project which contains a framework with a private protocol. And I need to create a class in the main project which conforms to that protocol (the framework contains check `conformsToProtocol:` so it doesn't accept very random classes).

The source code of the project and framework is available but I can't add significant changes into framework. For example I can't make that protocol public (because this framework is used in other projects) or disable `conformsToProtocol:`.

How to solve this issue?

P.S. Tried to find similar questions on stackoverflow but it shows "how to create private protocols" or "how to create private functions in protocol" only

Comment: Would it be possible to take a class that already conforms to that protocol and subclass it?
Anyway, if you can access one of these classes in Objective-C, you can also get the protocol instance (`class_copyProtocolList(_:_:)`) and dynamically add it to another class using `class_addProtocol`.

Comment: I have already found `NSProtocolFromString()`+`class_addProtocol` solves the task with protocol conformance (without of using other classes conforming to that protocol). But I also need somehow add at least empty implementations of the new methods.

Comment: You can just implement those methods normally if you know how they are called. Create a normal class, implement those methods and only add the protocol conformance dynamically.

Comment: I can't just do that because that private protocol also involves private parameter types but it seems it should be a separate question

Comment: If you implement it in Objective-C, you can just use `id` in the parameter definitions.